# In flutter how to remove thick frame around DataTable2()

Tags: flutter, datatable, flutter-datatable

In flutter I am trying to create a `DataTable` using `DataTable2( )` Widget. By default it shows a horrible thick frame that occupies a lot of space. Anyone knows how to remove that? I have checked all properties but couldn't find anything relevant

[image]

===========  **Update** =============

I found the issue. It was the padding that was giving that was giving that effect - changed it to zero. The table still has a border, but much smaller.

```
return Card(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
```

Comment: Can you provide some code to reproduce the issue?